# Which browsers are supported by Semantic-UI-React?

Tags: reactjs, semantic-ui-react

I have searched for Browser support for Semantic UI react and I have found that Semantic UI (not react version) to support the following [version](https://github.com/Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI#browser-support)

> Browser Support :Last 2 Versions FF, Chrome, Safari Mac IE 11+ Android 4.4+, Chrome for Android 44+ iOS Safari 7+ Microsoft Edge 12+ Although some components will work in IE9, grids and other flexbox components are not supported by IE9 and may not appear correctly.

Is it safe to assume that semantic-ui react also follows the same minimum browser support? I could not find that info in their GitHub page or website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the Semantic UI React docs:

> Can I use a custom CSS theme?
>
> Yes. Semantic UI React includes components that render valid Semantic UI HTML, no CSS is included. This allows you to load any Semantic UI CSS theme on top of your Semantic UI React app.

Since you have to include your own CSS, you can pull those files from the official Semantic UI distribution and have their version support assurances.